# StockTrader RI > Controllers, Presenters, WTF?

Tags: wpf, design-patterns, prism

I am currently learning how to make advanced usage of WPF via the Prism (Composite WPF) project.

I watch many videos and examples and the demo application StockTraderRI makes me ask this question:

What is the exact role of each of the following part?

- SomethingService: Ok, this is something to manage data
- SomethingView: Ok, this is what's displayed
- SomethingPresentationModel: Ok, this contains data and commands for the view to bind to (equivalent to a ViewModel).
- SomethingPresenter: I don't really understand it's usage
- SomethingController: Don't understand too

I saw that a Presenter and a Controller are not necessary but I would like to understand why they are here. Can someone tell me their **role** and **when** to use them?

Comment: I agree, things a confusing freaking mess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had [exactly the same problem](http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/Thread/View.aspx?ThreadId=50763) when I first went through Prism.

`Controllers` are basically for logic that spans an entire module, whereas `Presenters` are for logic that is specific to a `View`.

For example, a `Presenter` would respond to a command that results in a button in the view being disabled. A `Controller` would respond to a command that results in the `View` (and `Presenter`) being changed entirely, or perhaps loading a different View/Presenter in a different region in the module's shell.

**Edit:** As for when to use them, you can skip the `Controller` entirely if you have no need for the orchestration mentioned above. The simplest application will just have a:

- `Module`: registers the view/presenter into the `Region`
- `Presenter`: responds to commands from the view and modifies the `ViewModel`.
- `ViewModel`: adapter between `Presenter` and `View` that implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)
- `View`: binds to `ViewModel` and displays UI

**Edit:** As for Presenter vs ViewModel, most of your logic should be in your Presenter. Think of your ViewModel as housing the logic for your view, but the Presenter as dealing with the consequences of interacting with the view.

For example, the user clicks the "Search" button in your `View`. This triggers an `ICommand`, which is handled by your `Presenter`. The `Presenter` begins the search and sets the `ViewModel.IsSearching` property, which fires the PropertyChanged notification for `CanSearch`. `CanSearch` is a readonly property that is based on several other properties (eg. `IsSearchEnabled && !IsSearching`). The "Search" button in the `View` has its `Enabled` property bound to `CanSearch`.

Comment: Oh, so it's just a separation between what happens in the current view (Presenter) and what happens in the module (Controller).

I actually do all logic stuff in the ViewModel. Is this wrong or is this just a strategic choice?

Comment: `Prism` is just a recommendation. Having said that, I've updated my answer with some VM vs Presenter info.

Comment: Great, everything is now clear in my head. I'll try this now.
Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion Controller in here refers to [Application Controller](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/applicationController.html)

Comment: This is true for Prism if there is only one Module.